# A value of type 'String?' can't be assign to variable of type 'String' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i met a error on val... It says ,

> A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'String'.

**got error on this ,**
this code is in below full code

```
  onChanged: (val) => setState(
                                          () => _applyleavevalueChanged = val),
                                      validator: (val) { 
                                        setState(
                                            () => _applyleavevalueToValidate = val);
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                      onSaved: (val) => setState(
                                          () => _applyleavevalueSaved = val),
```

i met a error on val... It says ,

> A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'String'.

this is my full source code.....

File : `leaveapply.dart`

```
 import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';
    import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import './LeaveApply/BouncingButton.dart';
    import './LeaveApply/leave_history.dart';
    import 'LeaveApply/LeaveHistoryCard.dart';
    import 'LeaveApply/datepicker.dart';
    
  

  void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LeaveApply(),
        title: 'Leave Apply',
      ));
    }
    
    class LeaveApply extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LeaveApplyState createState() => _LeaveApplyState();
    }
    
    class _LeaveApplyState extends State<LeaveApply>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late Animation animation, delayedAnimation, muchDelayedAnimation, LeftCurve;
      late AnimationController animationController;
      final searchFieldController = TextEditingController();
    
      late TextEditingController _applyleavecontroller;
      String _applyleavevalueChanged = '';
      String _applyleavevalueToValidate = '';
      String _applyleavevalueSaved = '';
    
      late TextEditingController _fromcontroller;
      String _fromvalueChanged = '';
      String _fromvalueToValidate = '';
      String _fromvalueSaved = '';
    
      late TextEditingController _tocontroller;
      String _tovalueChanged = '';
      String _tovalueToValidate = '';
      String _tovalueSaved = '';
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // ignore: todo
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
    
        //SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
        _applyleavecontroller =
            TextEditingController(text: DateTime.now().toString());
        _fromcontroller = TextEditingController(text: DateTime.now().toString());
        _tocontroller = TextEditingController(text: DateTime.now().toString());
    
        animationController =
            AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
        animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));
    
        delayedAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController,
            curve: Interval(0.2, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
    
        muchDelayedAnimation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController,
            curve: Interval(0.3, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // ignore: todo
        // TODO: implement dispose
        animationController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        animationController.forward();
        final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
            new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
        return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animationController,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
                new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
            return Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                title: Text(
                  'Apply Leave',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                leading: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    size: 18.0,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
                elevation: 1.0,
              ),
              body: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15.0,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Apply Leave Date",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 13,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            // height: height * 0.06,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10,
                            ),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: width * 0.75,
                                    child: DateTimePicker(
                                      type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                                      dateMask: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                      controller: _applyleavecontroller,
                                      //initialValue: _initialValue,
                                      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                                      calendarTitle: "Leave Date",
                                      confirmText: "Confirm",
                                      enableSuggestions: true,
                                      //locale: Locale('en', 'US'),
                                      onChanged: (val) => setState(
                                          () => _applyleavevalueChanged = val),
                                      validator: (val) {
                                        setState(
                                            () => _applyleavevalueToValidate = val);
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                      onSaved: (val) => setState(
                                          () => _applyleavevalueSaved = val),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.calendar_today,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.03,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Choose Leave Type",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.02,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: DropdownSearch<String>(
                            validator: (v) => v == null ? "required field" : null,
                            hint: "Please Select Leave type",
                            mode: Mode.MENU,
                            showSelectedItems: true,
                            items: [
                              "Medical",
                              "Family",
                              "Sick",
                              'Function',
                              'Others'
                            ],
                            showClearButton: true,
                            onChanged: print,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Leave Date",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 13,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            // height: height * 0.06,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10,
                            ),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white38,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.calendar_today,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                      width: width * 0.28,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white38,
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                              blurRadius: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black26,
                                            )
                                          ]),
                                      child: CustomDatePicker(
                                        controller: _fromcontroller,
                                        title: "From",
                                        onchanged: (val) =>
                                            setState(() => _fromvalueChanged = val),
                                        validator: (val) {
                                          setState(
                                              () => _fromvalueToValidate = val);
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        saved: (val) =>
                                            setState(() => _fromvalueSaved = val),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Transform(
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                      width: width * 0.28,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white38,
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                            blurRadius: 2,
                                            color: Colors.black26,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: CustomDatePicker(
                                        controller: _tocontroller,
                                        title: "To",
                                        onchanged: (val) => setState(() {
                                          _tovalueChanged = val;
                                          print(val);
                                        }),
                                        validator: (val) {
                                          setState(() => _tovalueToValidate = val);
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        saved: (val) =>
                                            setState(() => _tovalueSaved = val),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Apply Leave Date",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 13,
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              // height: height * 0.06,
                              height: height * 0.25,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                //autofocus: true,
                                minLines: 1,
                                maxLines: 10,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  suffixIcon: searchFieldController.text.isNotEmpty
                                      ? IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                          onPressed: () => WidgetsBinding.instance
                                              ?.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
                                                  searchFieldController.clear()))
                                      : null,
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              muchDelayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Attach Document",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () async {},
                              child: Text(
                                "Click  to Upload Documents",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff2876bd),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                              delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                          child: Bouncing(
                            onPress: () {},
                            child: Container(
                              //height: 20,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color: Color(0xff2876bd),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Request Leave",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              child: Text(
                                'LeaveHistory',
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => LeaveHistory(
                                          // leavetype: '',
                                          // description: '',
                                          // status: '',
                                          // requesteddate: '',
                                          // verifieddate: '',
                                          )),
                                );
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add `!` at the end of `val` like `val!`. Does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value type of `_applyleavevalueChanged` is `String` and
the value type of `val` is `String?`

if `val` can be `null`

```dart
_applyleavevalueChanged = val ?? ''; // '' is the default value in case val is null
```

or

```dart
if (val != null) {
    _applyleavevalueChanged = val!; // ! mark that the val is definitely not null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get came from null-safety, the type `String?` means that it could be either a `String`, or `null`, but your variable only accepts a `String`, and no `null`.

For this, you can "force" the use of 'non-null' variable by adding a ! at the end of your variable, but be careful when doing this.

```dart
 _applyleavevalueToValidate = val!
```

You can learn more about null-safety syntax and principles on the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html.

Comment: yes, successfully solved....thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set default value like this. For example,

```
String? a;
String x = a ?? "default value";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update of Flutter, they've made it mandatory to provide non-null values for all variables. So, if you have a chance of encountering a null value in the onChanged callback of a DropdownButton, you'll get an error message like this: "A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'."

To fix this issue, you can simply add the ! operator to the value variable like so:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedCurrency,
  items: dropDownItems,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCurrency = value!;
    });
  },
);
```

By appending ! to value, you're essentially asserting to the compiler that the value won't be null. This ensures that you're providing a non-null value as required.